# Custom resizing of images using AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm already using a py function that automatically resizes stuff to 128x128 approximately (if it's a square picture its 128x128, if not, width is 128, and height scales according to it.

However, I would like to change that value to 450 for width, and then it can auto scale for height. However, whenever I change the original CreateThumbnail.py (128x128) to this:

```
def resize_image(image_path, resized_path):
    with Image.open(image_path) as image:
        image.thumbnail((450, 128))
        image.save(resized_path)
```

And zip it again, Lambda says that it couldn't find "CreateThumbnail.py". Now, I have no idea why it would do that, considering I didn't change anything like imports and stuff, only that single numerical value. Any ideas?

Comment: Does the edited code work locally?

Comment: Sounds like a simple mistake during the zip process, specifically, this would happen if you included the outer folder in the zip when you actually need only its contents in the root of the zip.  Open the zip file and confirm that `CreateThumbnail.py` is not in a folder within the zip file.

Comment: Yup, that was it Michael, thanks!